# Jenkins /var/log/jenkins takes 7GB in two weeks

Tags: logging, jenkins, diskspace

After about two weeks of usage I have found out that

> /var/log/jenkins

takes around 7Gb of disk space. Is there any way to disable logging so it won't take so much space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup log rotation daemon of some sort, look at the following links:

- [logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/)
- [syslog-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng)
- [nice tutorial about logrotate on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: thank you, I have now succesfully setup logrotate using this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: np, I add this tutorial to the answer.